# how to execute python function from module without pip install

Tags: python, pip

How can I execute python function from a package without main / pip install in editable mode

e.g.

my sample.py is

```
def cli():
    print("I'm running myTest")
    return 0
```

and setup.py as

```
setup(
    name="sample",
    version="1.0",
    py_modules=["sample"],
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        sample=sample:cli
    """,
)
```

now if I do `pip install -e .` and execute `sample`
I get desired o/p as

```
I'm running myTest
```

However with this I'm not able to debug it,
What's ideal way to execute function from a module without pip install / using another python file,

also tried with `python -m sample` but that gives no o/p since there is no `entrypoint`

Comment: "*I'm not able to debug it*" Why? What's the problem? `pip install -e` is exactly for debugging — it installs the package in such a way that you can edit and run it without reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

So call your function in your `sample.py`:

```
def cli():
    print("I'm running myTest")
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Then, from the command line:

```
python sample.py
```

See here for what `if __name__ == "__main__":` means:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/

If you want to leave `sample.py` completely unmodified, then you just create a new file `test_sample.py` and `import sample` to use it like so:

```
import sample

sample.cli()
```

or, as an alternative method of import, `test_sample.py` can also be:

```
from sample import cli

cli()
```

Then you run:

```
python test_sample.py
```

Just make sure `test_sample.py` is in the same directory as `sample.py`.